# Polymorphic Button With Next.js Link and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, polymorphism

I am trying to build a polymorphic `Button` component that either renders a Next.js link or a `button`, depending on the `as` prop.

```
import { ComponentPropsWithoutRef, ElementType, ReactNode } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

type OwnProps<T extends ElementType = ElementType> = {
  as?: T;
  variant?: "primary" | "secondary" | "neutral" | "danger" | "text";
};

type Props<T extends ElementType> = OwnProps<T> & Omit<ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>, keyof OwnProps>;

export default function Button<T extends ElementType = "button" | "a">({
  as,
  variant = "primary",
  ...props
}: Props<T>) {
  const Component = as === "a" ? Link : "button";

  return <Component {...props} />;
}
```

While this code works fine and compiles, TypeScript complains with the following error on the `<Component {...props} />`:

```
Type 'Omit<Props<T>, "as" | "variant">' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, keyof InternalLinkProps> & ... 4 more ... & ButtonHTMLAttributes<...>'.
  Property 'href' is missing in type 'Omit<Props<T>, "as" | "variant">' but required in type 'InternalLinkProps'.ts(2322)
link.d.ts(11, 5): 'href' is declared here.
```

If I understand it correctly, it's because the `href` attribute is required in Next.js' `LinkProps`, but it can be `undefined` given my current types, as a `button` wouldn't need it.

What's the best way of fixing this issue?